# need a regex that would delete line endings in text file, except those in blank lines

Tags: regex

Please see the image:

[image]

What regex would delete all line endings only from non-blank lines (not deleting them from blank lines? This is from a text file of over 8000 lines.

64-bit Vista.

Answer (score 1):

My messy method would be to open it in word, do a find and replace on ^p^p (two end paragraphs in a row) with some character not used in the file, like "|".  Then I would replace all ^p with just a space.  Then I would go back and replace t he "|" with ^p.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to convert paragraphs that have line breaks at the end of each line to continuous text within each paragraph:

> Now is the time for all good\n
>   men to come to the aid of their\n
>   country\n
>   \n

into

> Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country\n
>   \n

Then something like this should work:

```
sed -n '1{x;d};H;${x;s|\([^\n]\)\n\([^\n]\)|\1 \2|gp}' file
```

or

```
sed ':a;$!N;s|^\n||;s|\n\([^\n]\+\)$| \1|;ta;p;D' file
```

Answer (score 0):

It kind of depends on what regex package you have, whether you have lookahead or not.

I'd personally do:

-- remove trailing whitespace, this makes sure that 'blank' lines are \n\n

`s/^[ \t][ \t]*$//`

-- if it's a singular linefeed, substitute

`s/([^\n])\n([^\n])/\1 \2/`

it really depends on your regex package

Answer (score 0):

with sed i would do something like:

```
sed 's/[ \t]*$//'
```